# Cloudflare scrubbing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when in Under Attack Mode

Tags: header, cors, cloudflare, access-control, ddos

I need to be able to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header with my server, however when I switch to Under Attack Mode (which I need right now because I'm being DDOSed), Cloudflare scrubs this and a bunch of other headers which is breaking some site functionality I need.

I sent a message to Cloudflare and am waiting to hear back, any ideas in the meantime?

Comment: Hi  @Anthony, any solution for this? Experiencing the same issue